# Getting value hexadecimal 0x02, character not valid

Tags: c#, closedxml

I am getting the following error:

> , value hexadecimal 0x02, caracter not valid.

using this code:

```
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
  wb.Worksheets.Add(dt1);
  Response.Clear();
  Response.Buffer = true;
  Response.Charset ="";    
  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-     officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
  //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridView.xlsx");
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
  using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
      wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
      MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
      Response.Flush();
      Response.End();
  }
```

}

I have tried different ways, but I still get the same error. "dt1" is filled from stored procedure.

Comment: if you are wanting to add a datatable to XLWorkBook, you are doing this incorrectly..
after you create `wb` then you need to create a worksheet by the way would be the name of your worksheet which is a string for example `var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("My Test WorkSheet");` which will show up at the bottom of the Excel when it's opened. then to add the datatable to the worksheet you need to specify a cell range something like this 
`ws.Cell(11, 1).InsertTable(dt1.AsEnumerable());`

Comment: I posted a working example using ClosedXML I know this works because I just tested it as well..

Comment: @MethodMan You can add a DataTable as a new Worksheet, see the [documentation](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Adding%20DataTable%20as%20Worksheet&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: From the error message I think the DataTable holds invalid string data.

Comment: @Raidri you can add a Datatable but it must be Inserted for starters.. also the worksheet name is what he should name it ..not the entire datatable.. I have tested out my solution and it works vs what the OP is trying to do.. being that the OP is not adding a DataTable based on the way that the `ClosedXML` documentation is showing the OP must have some extraneous data in the datatable if that's the case I also have a method that I can post that will remove things like `html` characters if they are present in the DataTable

Answer (score 0):

to use ClosedXML I am currently doing the following and I call this method to open the Excel from a web page.

to call the ExportToExcel_SomeReport you would do it like this I create a public static class called Extensions

```
Extensions.ExportToXcel_SomeReport(dt1, fileName, this.Page);//Call the method on your button click 

//this will be in the static public class you create
internal static void ExportToXcel_SomeReport(DataTable dt, string fileName, Page page)
{
    var recCount = dt.Rows.Count;
    fileName = string.Format(fileName, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_hhmmss"));
    var xlsx = new XLWorkbook();
    var ws = xlsx.Worksheets.Add("Some Custom Report");
    ws.Style.Font.Bold = true;
    ws.Cell("C5").Value = "Some Custom Header Report";
    ws.Cell("C5").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Black;
    ws.Cell("C5").Style.Font.SetFontSize(16.0);
    ws.Cell("E5").Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    ws.Range("C5:E5").Style.Font.SetFontSize(16.0);
    ws.Cell("A7").Value = string.Format("{0} Records", recCount);
    ws.Style.Font.Bold = false;
    ws.Cell(9, 1).InsertTable(dt.AsEnumerable());
    ws.Row(9).InsertRowsBelow(1);
   // ws.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Gray;
    ws.Columns("1-8").AdjustToContents();
    ws.Tables.Table(0).ShowAutoFilter = true;
    ws.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
    DynaGenExcelFile(fileName, page, xlsx);
}

private static void DynaGenExcelFile(string fileName, Page page, XLWorkbook xlsx)
{
    page.Response.ClearContent();
    page.Response.ClearHeaders();
    page.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", fileName));

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xlsx.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.WriteTo(page.Response.OutputStream);
        memoryStream.Close();
    }
    page.Response.Flush();
    page.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: This works there must be something different that you are doing I can't tell without seeing your entire code..